# Odd power of cos

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometric-series

Maybe it's a dumb question but it's new for me and I want to understant it clearly.

Why or which method is used there, I have formula

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\cos^{2n+1}x
 = \frac{1}{2^{2n}}
   \left\{\cos((2n+1)x) +  {{2n+1}\choose 1 }\cos((2n-1)x)+ \ldots+ {{2n+1}\choose n}\cos(x) \right\}$$

I need to know why I can obtain that series. Never seen writen the odd power of $ \cos $ like that.
Thank you for anwsering and have a nice day.

Comment: Are you comfortable using the complex number definition of $\cos$ instead?  This can often lead to these sorts of identities having far simpler proofs.  Note that $\cos(z) = \frac{e^{zi}+e^{-zi}}{2}$ and so $(\cos(z))^{2n+1} = \frac{(e^{zi}+e^{-zi})^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}}$.  From here, try applying the binomial theorem and cancel and group terms where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$z=cos(x)+i \sin(x)$$
Then 
$$\frac{1}{z}=\cos(x)-i \sin(x) \\
z+\frac{1}{z}=2 \cos(x) \\
\cos(x)= \frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z}) \\
\cos{2n+1}(x)= \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}(z+\frac{1}{z})^{2n+1}
$$

Now, by the Binomial theorem, and using $\binom{2n+1}{k}=\binom{2n+1}{2n+1-k}$ you get
$$\cos{2n+1}(x)= \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}(\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{2n+1}{k} (z^k+\frac{1}{z^k})$$

Use the Demoivre formula to see that 
$$z^k+\frac{1}{z^k}=2 \cos((2k+1)x)$$